# Assist me understand obj-c class types

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am studying apple obj-c guide and i am having problem understanding class types, the doc says

> A class definition is a specification for a kind of object. The class,
>   in effect, defines a data type. The type is based not just on the data
>   structure the class defines (instance variables), but also on the
>   behavior included in the definition (methods). A class name can appear
>   in source code wherever a type specifier is permitted in C—for
>   example, as an argument to the sizeof operator:

```
int i = sizeof(Rectangle);
```

And sizeof is operator not c method?

And please also clear me what this means

```
Objects are always "typed by" a pointer.
```

Comment: did you also read [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html)? It starts with explaining OOP and how it is done in ObjC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but probably you should start from something easier then obj-c.

In OOP (object-oriented programming) you start from base types (int, long, char, sometimes string, etc.).
Then you have class that contains base types properties and methods (similarly to struct in C).

A class can usually be instantiated, that means you create a object of that type. E.g.

```
class Person {

    int age;

    string name;
    string surname;

    void printFullName() {

        Console.WriteLine(name + " " + surname);

    }

}
```

If you write

```
var myperson = new Person();
```

you created a new object of type Person, with

```
myperson.printFullName();
```

you can access its method printFullName()

In the example **sizeof** is a C unary operator (like ++ or --) and **Rectangle** is a type, a class.
By the way, that example is a bit confusing, search for another one.

> Objects are always "typed by" a pointer.

means that any object you create is typized by a pointer that defines its type.
Mmmh, it's hard to explain :)

Hope this code can help you :)

Comment: thanks teejay for your advice ... but its my requirement ... have to do ... thats why asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sizeof() is from c. Objective-C is an extension of c, so everything you can do in c, you can do in objective-c.

> Objects are always "typed by" a pointer.

This means that you always reference an object by a pointer to an instance of it. I hope you are familiar with C++ as I'm going to use it to demonstrate this practically...

```
// C++ "typed by pointer"
Object *obj = new Object();
obj->member = NULL;

// Obj-C "typed by pointer"
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
obj.property = nil;


// C++
Object obj;
obj.member = NULL;

// Obj-C
NSObject obj; // THIS WILL NOT COMPILE
```

Hope that makes some sense.

EDIT

> I have amended the comments in my original answer to clarifiy "typed
>   by". – Chris Heyes 8 mins ago
>
> "static typing" or "strong typing" imposes restrictions on operations
>   on objects or data types. Where as "weak typing" does not, allowing
>   operator overloaded. – Chris Heyes 5 mins ago
>
> An example of "generic typing" is referencing an abstract class (read
>   up on polymorphism). This is "weak typing" in that that inherited
>   objects can be referred to by a "generic" pointer declared to the
>   compiler as an abstract object type. (NOTE: Try not to confuse,
>   "typing" and class/data types as these are different) – Chris Heyes 49
>   secs ago edit

Comment: thanks a lot for lovely reply, these term confuse me "typed by", "static typing", "generically typed id". Why word typed or typing is used. Please clarify "class types" bit more.

Comment: I have amended the comments in my original answer to clarifiy "typed by".

Comment: "static typing" or "strong typing" imposes restrictions on operations on objects or data types. Where as "weak typing" does not, allowing operator overloaded.

Comment: An example of "generic typing" is referencing an abstract class (read up on polymorphism). This is "weak typing" in that that inherited objects can be referred to by a "generic" pointer declared to the compiler as an abstract object type. (NOTE: Try not to confuse, "typing" and class/data types as these are different)